# Unable to find a value for "length" in object of class "java.lang.String" using operator "."

Tags: java, string, spring, jsp, jstl

Why does this JSTL expression not seem to be able to use the length method of the String class:

```
    <c:when test="${displayName != null && displayName.length > 0 }">
        <p><c:out value="${displayName}"/></p>
    </c:when>
```

It produces this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: Unable to find a value for "length" in object 
of class "java.lang.String" using operator "."
```

I have included the following tag libraries at the top of the JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="decorator" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access only getters (`getSomething`) like this. To find string size, try `fn:length(displayName)`. Naturally, `fn` namespace should be imported:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Also, you can replace this all with `empty` check: `${not empty displayName}`

Answer (score 2):

See if [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/UsingtheJSTLfunctions.htm) helps.

You'll have to add

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```